# MySQL select statement is not using the index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have one table called T.
It has 4 attributes: x, y, z and w.

I loaded the table with data.
Then, created an index on x, and also another index on y.

Now, when I submit this query:

```
select count(*) from T where x <= 10 and y <=100;
```

I assume that index x and index y will be used.

However, that does not happen!

When I use the command EXPLAIN before the select statements, it shows index x and y as "`possible_keys`" BUT under the column "`key`" there is NULL.
That means no indexes were used.

Now, if I submit this query:

```
select count(*) from T where x<=50;
```

Then MySQL uses the index x, as the EXPLAIN command shows.

So, is the AND in the condition prevents from using the indexes or what exactly I have done wrong here?

Regards!

Comment: You may need to create an index on both fields.  Something like, `create index T_x_y on T (x, y)`

Comment: Can you please select an answer as your preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to index x and y together, More info here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

You can simply run this query :

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name_here` 
ADD INDEX `IDX_COMB_XY` (`x` ASC, `y` ASC) ;
```

Now run Explain and you will see IDX_COMB_XY will be used.

Comment: But what if my query is this: select count(*) from T where x<=50 and y<=10 and z<=30 and w<=7; ?? does this mean I should create a composition index for all the 4 attributes?! this will remove the benefits of indexing i think right?

Comment: No it will not remove the benefit of indexing, it will make your query faster. You might end up with multiple combo-index for "x y z", "x z", etc. It depend on what you want to put on WHERE statement.

Comment: I want MySQL to use index on attribute x to answer this query: select count(*) from T where x<=50 and y<=60 and z<=10 and w<=8;

Comment: Then create a multi column index of (x,y,z,w). As per mysql doc (referenced above) you can index up to 16 columns together

Comment: hmmm i believe a composite index (x,y,z,w) will not have any benefit since it would be similar to not having an index.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/22/multiple-column-index-vs-multiple-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can only use 1 index per table in a query. When there is more than index to choose from, MySQL will take an educated guess as to which one will be most beneficial, based on cardinality, memory requirements, number of records, etc.

@Mojtaba's answer explains how to create a multi-column index that MySQL will use in your scenario.

Comment: if MySQL can only use 1 index in a query, then why it didn't use index x when I ran this Q: select count(*) from T where x<=30 and y<=50;?

Comment: How many records are in your table? There is a cost to using an index, and scanning a small table can be faster, especially since it still needs to scan the rows for the value of y.

Comment: Have in mind that you can also hint mysql to use or not use specific index. Which in your case I'm pretty sure it wont help but play with it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Your question is why won't MySQL use both indices, which is because it can't. As for why it is not using either one, I can only guess it is because you are using range queries, and MySQL believes it is faster to not use an index at all. To solve your problem, follow @Mojtaba's instructions.